# Thunderbolt to VGA connector makes my MacBook Pro Retina very hot

Tags: macbook-pro, bootcamp, windows, thunderbolt

I have a new Macbook pro retina display, i7, 16 GB RAM and NVIDIA GeForce GT 750M.

I have noticed that when running Boot Camp with Win 7 and I plug in my HP VGA monitor using a VGA/thunderbolt adaptor, the top area above the function keys get extremely hot.

I have made sure I have the most up to date drivers for my graphics card but still the issue persists.

Has anyone else experienced this?

Comment: Why, in 2013, do you want to use a (poor-quality, low-resolution) VGA monitor with such a sophisticated and expensive MacBook with such high-end graphics capabilities? Would you not be better served by buying an affordable high-resolution monitor that supports DVI, DisplayPort or HDMI? You will certainly get a much better-quality image.

Comment: I understand what you are saying and I do have monitor hooked up which supports DVI. I am being greedy and want a 3rd monitor and the only spare is a crappy old VGA.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well your macbook is simply utilizing the nvidia video card and that produces more heat.  Since you are running Windows it may not be using resources as efficiently as your MacOS.

Your macbook typically runs off the onboard video card and switches to the hotter running nvidia for intensive apps/games.

There are many posts regarding macs running hot using windows:
http://forums.macrumors.com/showthread.php?t=883774

Comment: I spoke with Apple support and they are happy that the MacBook is running within the acceptable heat threshold of 50-90 degrees.

I will keep an eye out for new nvidia drivers.

Comment: don't forget to upvote / mark as accepted for answer you think helped on your question.